# Setting to always keep Mac's USB ports alive?

Tags: mac, usb, sleep-wake

I have USB keyboards and mice that turn off when the computer is set to sleep, and then I am unable to wake up the computer due to that. And also, the backlight on the keyboard often just turns on and off randomly when the computer is asleep.

Is there an NVRAM option or some other tool to keep the USB ports active, even if the computer goes asleep?

Using a Macmini8,1

Comment: Are you saying that you can't wake the mac by pressing a key or moving the mouse? That's unusual. What brand/model are they? Are you using the 2 USB-A sockets at the back, or are they going through a hub?

Comment: Going through a hub, I can wake up most of the time using the mouse but not with my keyboard. Either way, that's a small issue. Bigger issue is the constant on and off behaviour of the keyboard backlight. It would be much preferred if the USB was always active so that would not be an issue. My USB DAC also turns off when the Mac goes to sleep which is a bit inconvenient too.

Comment: If you remove your hub, does the backlight issue go away?

Comment: Yep. Try connecting them directly. Sounds like the hub is the problem.

Comment: I don't have enough USB ports for peripherals so I have to use a hub. And still, I just want to have my USB ports powered while the Mac is sleeping. Is that too difficult to understand?

Comment: If Macs always turned off USB power during sleep, then no-one would ever be able to wake them again [except for laptops]. As this is clearly not the case, the issue must be elsewhere… like in the hub. What's even stranger is that you can wake it with the mouse - that option was removed years ago, in maybe El Capitan, because it was too easy to accidentally wake them by knocking the desk. Apple moved to spacebar to wake.

Comment: @Tetsujin Macs still wake on a mouse click. (My TrackPad, at least, will wake the Mac if I click it, but not if I swipe on it.)

Comment: hmm, yeah, mouse-click. They used to wake on mouse shake, maybe that's what I was thinking of. Used to be really irritating. I used to turn my mouse over if I didn't want it to wake, or just walking past the desk could jog it. [In testing that, I just proved to myself that not only does the USB stay powered but also the wireless Logi dongle plugged into my wired keyboard.]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely not the Mac itself (and therefore nothing you can 'correct') -- but rather your hub, which is between the peripherals and the Mini.

You can test this by connecting the keyboard directly to the Mini, and see if it works properly.

Other hubs may work better. I've used Anker USB-C to multi USB A hubs with a 2018 Mini with no problem.

Comment: Macs are supposed to put USB devices to sleep when the computer is supposed to go to sleep. That’s how they’re designed to be, but on my Lenovo laptop there’s an option to make the USB always on even if the laptop is off. I’m certain there must be an NVRAM option similar to this.

Comment: @Piipperi800 And yet I've always been able to wake my Mini using the mouse and Keyboard, without any alteration. Have you tried testing the keyboard directly into the Mini?

Comment: Yes I have, and it still just turns off and on every few minutes. But how would plugging directly into the Mac mini solve anything, when just as I explained, it is by default designed to turn all of them off?

Comment: @Piipperi800 Well, maybe it's the third-party keyboard. As said: I've been able to wake my 2018 Mini from sleep by pressing the Apple keyboard or touching the USB Apple Trackpad.

Comment: I use a 3rd party keyboard and it shouldn’t matter what keyboard I use. And I don’t get why you are constantly telling me that, when the core issue is how the Mac is designed by default to turn off the ports. All I want is to keep them on.

Comment: @Piipperi800 Can you provide evidence that Mac are designed to turn off the ports? This would mean that external drives would have to be unmounted and remounted again. A quick Google shows lots of people trying to turn USB devices OFF at sleep, not so much the other way round. It is enturely possible that some third-party peripherals designed for Windows PCs may expect a slightly different environment.

Comment: Maybe not entirely turn off. But they are put to a sleep mode, which not all devices support properly. If you have a backlit USB keyboard, you'd know what I am talking about. But it sounds like you don't, so it's not worth fighting over this. Especially since you're just looking for the same stuff I looked at on Google. What I need is an NVRAM command or something similar to tell the BIOS to treat the USB differently in sleep mode.

Comment: @Piipperi800 Desktop Macs do not sleep in the same way that laptop Macs sleep: e.g. no hibernation mode, because power consumption is not an issue. You could try using `pmset` to change the power management options; but I don't think there's a specific option for USB devices. (Also, Macs don't have BIOS.) But you are also saying that backlit keyboards don't support the Mac's sleep mode, which again points to the keyboard, not the Mac. We're not fighting: I am trying to help you with your problem! ;-)